Can't make a Simpson rule algorithm working in C++: works for some functions and some numbers, but not for others. Tried multiple methods to no avail
I was trying to make a little c++ program that integrates using the Simpson rule, but while I was testing I found out that it only works for some functions and some intervals. For example it works for sqrt(1+x) between 0 and 3 but not between 1 and 3 or 2 and 3. Here I'll put a minimal of my code.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double func1(double x); //All the function I'll be integrating
double func2(double x);
double func3(double x);
double func4(double x);

double Simpson(double (*F)(double), double a, double b, int N); //a and b are the extremes of integration,
                                                                //N is the number of intervals and F is the function that will be integrated
int main() {

        cout<<setprecision(10); //So we can see more decimal points

        int N=2000; //Giving a big enough N to have a decent precision, then I'll proceed to make some testing

        cout<<"exp(-x) between 0 and 1"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func1, 0, 1, N)<<"  Exact: "<<0.6321205588<<endl<<endl; //This works

        cout<<"exp(-x) between 0 and 2"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func1, 0, 2, N)<<"  Exact: "<<0.8646647167<<endl<<endl; //This works

        cout<<"exp(-x) between 0 and 3"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func1, 0, 3, N)<<"  Exact: "<<0.9502129316<<endl<<endl; //This works

        cout<<"sqrt(1+x) between 0 and 3"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func2, 0, 3, N)<<"  Exact: "<<4.666666667<<endl<<endl; //This works

        cout<<"sqrt(1+x) between 1 and 3"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func2, 1, 3, N)<<"  Exact: "<<3.447715251<<endl<<endl; //This doesn't

        cout<<"sqrt(1+x) between 2 and 3"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func2, 2, 3, N)<<"  Exact: "<<1.869231717<<endl<<endl; //This doesn't

        cout<<"Polinomial between -1 and 5"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func3, -1, 5, N)<<"  Exact: "<<-13.2<<endl<<endl; //This doesn't

        cout<<"Polinomial between 0 and 5"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func3, 0, 5, N)<<"  Exact: "<<-15.3125<<endl<<endl; //This doesn't

        cout<<"Polinomial between 1 and 5"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func3, 1, 5, N)<<"  Exact: "<<-16.63333333<<endl<<endl; //This doesn't

        cout<<"Si(0.8)"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func4, 0, 0.8, N)<<"  Exact: "<<0.7720957855<<endl<<endl; //This works

        cout<<"Si(1)"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func4, 0, 1, N)<<"  Exact: "<<0.9460830704<<endl<<endl; //This works

        cout<<"Si(2)"<<endl;
        cout<<"S: "<<Simpson(func4, 0, 2, N)<<"  Exact: "<<1.605412977<<endl<<endl; //This works


}

//Here I'll be defining all the functions I want to integrate. there's an exponential, a square root, a polynomial and Si.

double func1(double x) {
    return exp(-x);
}

double func2(double x) {
    return sqrt(1+x);
}

double func3(double x) {
    return 1-x+x*x*2+x*x*x/3+x*x*x*x/4-x*x*x*x*x/8;
}

double func4(double x) {

    if (x==0) { //We don't want any pole in our equations, do we?
        return 1;
    }

    return sin(x)/x;
}

//I'll be defining my prototype of Simpson implementation now

double Simpson(double (*F)(double), double a, double b, int N) {

    double h=(a+b)/N; //Defining the lenght of the N intervals inside the bigger interval [a,b]
    double Sum=F(a)+F(b); //Defining the Sum. I'm already putting in the extremes since the weights are 1/3 only for the 1st (i=0) and last (i=N) part,
                          //so I sum them here to avoid a "if-else if"" statement that would be less efficient.

    for (int i=1; i<N; i++) { //Starting the for cycle to sum all the other parts of the integration

        Sum+=2*(1+i%2)*F(a+i*h); //The odd parts have 4/3 weights (given by 2*(1+1) where the second 1 the i_odd%2)
                                 //while the even have 2/3 (given by 2*(1+0) where 0 is i_even%2)
                                 //I sum all of them

    }

    Sum*=h/3; //I finally multiply by h and divide by 3. I do it now to not multiply and divide eaxh

    return Sum; //I return Sum

}


I tried implementing a variable instead of using the "%" to get the alternate weights 4 and 2 for odd and even terms like this:
double Simpson(double (*F)(double), double a, double b, int N) {

    double h=(a+b)/N; //Defining the lenght of the N intervals inside the bigger interval [a,b]
    double Sum=F(a)+F(b); //Defining the Sum. I'm already putting in the extremes since the weights are 1/3 only for the 1st (i=0) and last (i=N) part,
                          //so I sum them here to avoid a "if-else if"" statement that would be less efficient.
    double w=4.;          //Define a weight equal to 4
    for (int i=1; i<N; i++) { //Starting the for cycle to sum all the other parts of the integration

        Sum+=w*F(a+i*h); 
        w=6-w; //Redefine w as 6-w to always have 4 or 2. since I started with w=4 all odd i will have w=4 and all even i will have w=2

    }

    Sum*=h/3; //I finally multiply by h and divide by 3. I do it now to not multiply and divide eaxh

    return Sum; //I return Sum

}

But it's the same results of 7/12 correct. Then I tried a subobtimal method that calls the function multiple times
double Simpson(double (*F)(double), double a, double b, int N) {

    double h=(a+b)/N; //Defining the lenght of the N intervals inside the bigger interval [a,b]
    double Sum=0.; //Defining the Sum equal to 0 this time
    for (int i=1; i<N; i+=2) { //Starting the for cycle to sum all the other parts of the integration, i jumps by 2 instead of 1 to avoid counting
                                 //some terms twice

        Sum+=F(a+(i-1)*h)+4*F(a+i*h)+F(a+(i+1)*h); //Summing all the terms calling the function. subobtimal but in theory it works:
        //Odd i will always have a weight of 4/3 due to summing 2 to i each cycle. While the i=0 and i=N are only counted once,
        //all the even i are counted twice

    }

    Sum*=h/3; //I finally multiply by h and divide by 3. I do it now to not multiply and divide eaxh

    return Sum; //I return Sum

}

Still 7/12. In a last ditch effort I tried a "if else if":
double Simpson(double (*F)(double), double a, double b, int N) {

    double h=(a+b)/N; //Defining the lenght of the N intervals inside the bigger interval [a,b]
    double Sum=0.; //Defining the Sum equal to 0 this time
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (i==0 || i==N) { //If it's the first or last term it weights 1/3
            Sum+=F(a+i*h);
        } else if (i%2==0) { //Otherwise, if i is even it weights 2/3
            Sum+=2*F(a+i*h);
        } else {//Lastly, as the only option left i is odd it weights 4/3
            Sum+=4*F(a+i*h);
        }
    }

    Sum*=h/3; //I finally multiply by h and divide by 3. I do it now to not multiply and divide each time

    return Sum; //I return Sum

}

But it still gave wrong results for the same 7 calculations.
I don't understand what's wrong and where. I tried with multiples methods and it still always gave the same right and wrong results, so it makes me think it's in how I give the command in main. However I can't find anything wrong there, so maybe the problem lies with how I wrote the Simpson function, but I tried with 4 very different approach, it's very unlikely that I commited an error that gave the same results in all four.
So maybe I should look into the parts of the function that I didn't touch, like how I defined h or the multiplication by h/3 before returning. But again I can't find anything wrong there.
Can someone help and explain what I'm doing wrong?

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Can someone help and explain what I'm doing wrong? -- Next time, 1) Do a hand-calculation first, and then 2) Use a debugger to determine which step in the code starts to differ from your hand calculation.  Also read this.  If you had done a hand calculation of the function you were testing, you would have more than likely found the error yourself when you started single-stepping through the code with a debugger.

Computing h is wrong since you should have double h=(b-a)/N;
Note that your exact values for func3 seem to be wrong; for instance by using gp/pari, we define:
func3(x)=1-x+x*x*2+x*x*x/3+x*x*x*x/4-x*x*x*x*x/8;
intnum(x=-1,5,func3(x))
intnum(x=0,5,func3(x))
intnum(x=1,5,func3(x))

and get
-39.200000000000000000000000000000000000
-41.354166666666666666666666666666666667
-42.633333333333333333333333333333333333


Oh my thank you it was such a dumb mistake. Thanks also for pointing out the func3 stuff, I actually wrote it wrong it was supposed to be ..+(x^3)/2+...

You're welcome! Sometimes when one looks too hard, it becomes easy to miss something that afterwards seems obvious. It happened to me so many times :)
